# Is there function that can remove the outliers?

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I find a function to detect outliers from columns but I do not know how to remove the outliers

is there a function for excluding or removing outliers from the columns

Here is the function to detect the outlier but I need help in a function to remove the outliers

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
outliers=[]
def detect_outlier(data_1):

    threshold=3
    mean_1 = np.mean(data_1)
    std_1 =np.std(data_1)


    for y in data_1:
        z_score= (y - mean_1)/std_1 
        if np.abs(z_score) > threshold:
            outliers.append(y)
    return outliers
```

Here the printing outliers

```
#printing the outlier 
outlier_datapoints = detect_outlier(df['Pre_TOTAL_PURCHASE_ADJ'])
print(outlier_datapoints)
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to use [`scipy.stats.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html)

```py
from scipy.stats import zscore
# calculates z-score values
df["zscore"] = zscore(df["Pre_TOTAL_PURCHASE_ADJ"]) 

# creates `is_outlier` column with either True or False values, 
# so that you could filter your dataframe accordingly
df["is_outlier"] = df["zscore"].apply(lambda x: x <= -1.96 or x >= 1.96)
```

Comment: thank you for your quick respond I got error in this code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     df["is_outlier"] = df["zscore"].apply(x: x <= -1.96 or x >= 1.96)

Comment: @swe2010 I'm glad I could help. For my thesis research, I needed to calculate z-score values too haha. there might be a better way but this worked fine for me.

Comment: @swe2010 btw don't forget to accept a correct answer so that this post wouldn't show up as 'unanswered'

Answer (score 1):

I presume that by "remove the outliers" you mean "remove rows from the `df` dataframe which contain an outlier in the `'Pre_TOTAL_PURCHASE_ADJ'` column." If this is incorrect, perhaps you could revise the question to make your meaning clear.

Sample data are also helpful, rather than forcing would-be answerers to formulate their own.

It's generally much more efficient to avoid iterating over the rows of a dataframe. For row selections so-called [Boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) is a fast way of achieving your ends. Since you already have a *predicate* (function returning a truth value) that will identify the rows you want to exclude, you can use such a predicate to build another dataframe that contains only the outliers, or (by negating the predicate) only the non-outliers.

Since @political_scientist has already given a practical solution using `scipy.stats.zscore` to produce the predicate values in a new `is_outlier` column I will leave this answer as simple, general advice for working in numpy and pandas. Given that answer, the rows you want would be given by

```
df[~df['is_outlier']]
```

though it might be slightly more comprehensible to include the negation (`~`) in the generation of the selector column rather than in the indexing as above, renaming the column `'is_not_outlier'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def outlier():
    import pandas as pd
    df1=pd.read_csv("......\\train.csv")
    _, bp = pd.DataFrame.boxplot(df1, return_type='both')
    outliers = [flier.get_ydata() for flier in bp["fliers"]]
    out_liers = [i.tolist() for i in outliers]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 methods for one-dimentional datasets.

### Part 1: using upper and lower limit to 3 standard deviation

```
import numpy as np

# Function to Detection Outlier on one-dimentional datasets.
anomalies = []
def find_anomalies(data):
    # Set upper and lower limit to 3 standard deviation
    data_std = np.std(data)
    data_mean = np.mean(data)
    anomaly_cut_off = data_std * 3

    lower_limit = data_mean - anomaly_cut_off 
    upper_limit = data_mean + anomaly_cut_off

    # Generate outliers
    for outlier in data:
        if outlier > upper_limit or outlier < lower_limit:
            anomalies.append(outlier)
    return anomalies
```

### Part 2: Using IQR (interquartile range)

```
q1, q3= np.percentile(data,[25,75]) # get percentiles
iqr = q3 - q1 # the IQR value
lower_bound = q1 - (1.5 * iqr) # lower bound
upper_bound = q3 + (1.5 * iqr) # upper bound

np.sum(data > upper_bound) # how many datapoints are above the upper bound?
```