# How to compute and apply z score based on one column, and the apply it to that same column in Pyhton?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas data frame with 5 columns: X, Y Z, Value1, Value2.

I want to compute Z score based on column Value 1, and then apply it. I can't figure out how to do it properly. I have tried both

```
from scipy import stats
z_score = np.abs(stats.zscore(df["Value1"]))
df["Value1"] = df["Value1"][(z_score < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

and

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
df["Value1"].apply(zscore)
```

but non seems to work properly. Not sure what to do since I either key a

> KeyError: False or IndexError: tuple index out of range.

Comment: I realize that I messed up the format. Not sure what I am doing wrong exactly

Comment: can you please provide sample data for `df`?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do..? are you trying to filter?: `df.loc[z_score < 3]` Or are you checking if all are within the threshold of 3..? : `np.all(z_score < 3)`

Comment: I am trying to filter

Comment: Not sure but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57162033/10140310) could help.  @Zygos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there function that can remove the outliers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161413/is-there-function-that-can-remove-the-outliers)

Comment: if you want to slice those with a z_score less than 3 then this is the syntax: `df[df.z_score < 3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign a column called 'z_score' and use it in filtering.

```
df['z_score'] = np.abs(stats.zscore(df["Value1"]))
df.query('z_score > 3', inplace=True)  # If filter all DF.
df['Value1'] = df['Value1'].mask(df['z_score'] > 3)  # If filter by masking.
```